# Modified Printer Screwed up by manufacturer drivers

Tags: drivers, printer

My Canon printer has been modified to add ink without using catridges, but Canon driver software has detected this. Is there a way to block the ip ports that canon printer communicates with their own canon server or modify the software driver, so I can use my printer properly?

Comment: So by saying "*My Canon printer has been modified to add ink without using cartridges*" this means you made unsupported adjustments per the printer manufacturer or some mechanism within the device to detect otherwise.

Comment: What are the actual changes you made and why do you think there is a check being run against Webservice from Canon? Did you try to print without network access?

Answer (score 0):

If network connected, you could try blocking SNMP (161, 162) ports. If the driver does not use SNMP, try using a network sniffer (one of the free downloads perhaps) to find out what ports are used. Of course, it's quite likely the driver will refuse to send jobs to the printer if the ports are blocked and it does not get a response.

Failing all that, you could redesign the firmware in the printer...